# How to get high quality image avatar smack xmpp facebook

Tags: facebook, xmpp, smack, vcf-vcard

I used Vcard smack for get avatar image but it return to me image avatar size 32*32

It small image so I want to get high quality such as facebook do or other app do

could someone help me?

I try to search in gooogle but almost of thread said using Vcard for get avatar

I use to method below for get avatar with Vcard

=> my solution is using graphic api from facebook:

```
String urlAvatar = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + StringUtils.parseName(childrenEntryItems.getJid()).
replace("-", "") + "/picture?type=normal";
```

```html
public static byte[] getAvatarByteArray(XMPPConnection xmppConnection, String user) {
  VCard vCard = new VCard();
  SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(30000);
//  ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
//    new VCardProvider());
  try {
   vCard.load(xmppConnection, user);
  } catch (XMPPException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
//  Log.d("Giang", vCard.toXML() + " byte length = "
//    + vCard.getAvatar().length); // complete VCard information

  return vCard.getAvatar();
 }
 
 public static Bitmap makeBitemap(byte[] value) {
  if (value == null)
   return null;

  // Load only size values
  BitmapFactory.Options sizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(value, 0, value.length, sizeOptions);

  // Calculate factor to down scale image
  int scale = 1;
  int width_tmp = sizeOptions.outWidth;
  int height_tmp = sizeOptions.outHeight;
  while (width_tmp / 2 >= 256 && height_tmp / 2 >= 256) {
   scale *= 2;
   width_tmp /= 2;
   height_tmp /= 2;
  }

  // Load image
  BitmapFactory.Options resultOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  resultOptions.inSampleSize = scale;
  return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(value, 0, value.length,
    resultOptions);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best deal would be to store url of avatar in one of the custom v-cards and fetch it over HTTP using some image loading library. Remember that xmpp is a stream based architecture and I would be cautious to block the stream by sending large files.

Comment: I found another solution is using Graphic api from facebook, I had update my question, thank you